# Variable defined by a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing this Hackerrank challange [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/chingu-challenge-9-javascript-prep/challenges/insert-a-node-at-the-tail-of-a-linked-list) is the question:

> `Input` Format:
>
> You have to complete the `Node* Insert(Node* head, int data)` method. It takes 
>   two arguments: the head of the linked list and the integer to insert. You 
>   should not read any `input` from the `stdin`/console.
>
> `Output` Format :
>
> Insert the new node at the tail and just `return` the head of the updated linked list. Do not print anything to stdout/console.

```
/*
  Node is defined as
  var Node = function(data) {
      this.data = data;
      this.next = null;
  }
*/
```

And this is my code :

```
function insert(head, data) {
    if(head){
        while(head.next!==null){
            head = head.next;
        }
        head.next = Node(data);

    }else{
        head = Node(data);
    }
}
```

Does someone knows why it's wrong or can help me to understand how works?

Comment: @wrangler: No, it shouldn't.

Comment: The error is occurring in the else statement. Remember that scope is local, so the value at head is shadowed in that scope.

Comment: you actually don't return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return something, your code should look like this:

```
function(head, data) {
  if (head) {
    var nextNode = head

    while (nextNode.next !== null) {
      nextNode = nextNode.next
    }

    nextNode.next = new Node(data)
  } else {
    head = new Node(data)
  }

  return head
}
```

Comment: It works. Saves `head` in a variable and add `return` make it works. Thank you.